# In an acute-angle triangle $ABC$, find the minimum value of $5\tan A+2\tan B+ \tan C$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Question. In an acute-angle triangle $ABC$, what is the minimum value of $5\tan A+2\tan B+ \tan C$?

I have a form :

Given $5\tan A+2\tan B+\tan C$ in a $\triangle ABC$ and $A<90,B<90,C<90$.
The function $f(A,B)=5\tan A+2\tan B-\tan(A+B)$ has an extremum if 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(A,B)}{\partial A} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial f(A,B)}{\partial B} &= 0.
\end{align}
$$
This gives us
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5}{\cos^{2}A} &=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(A+B)} \\
\frac{2}{\cos^{2}B} &=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(A+B)},
\end{align}
$$
or
$$
\begin{align}
2\cos^{2}A &= 5\cos^{2}B \\
2\cos^{2}(A+B) &=\cos^{2}B.
\end{align}
$$
Since $A<90,B<90,C<90$, we write
$$
\sqrt{2}\cos A=\sqrt{5}\cos B \quad (1)
$$
and
$$
-\sqrt 2 \cos C=\sqrt 2 \cos(A+B)=-\cos B \quad (2).
$$
From (2): $\sqrt{2}\cos A\cos B-\sqrt{2}\sin A\sin B=\cos B$.
Using (1): 
$$
\sqrt{5}\cos^{2}B-\sqrt{2}\sin A\sin B=-\cos B,
$$
$$
\sqrt{5}\cos^{2}B+\cos B=\sqrt{2}\sin A\sin B.
$$
$$
(\sqrt{5}\cos^{2}B+\cos B)^{2}=2\sin^{2}A\sin^{2}B.
$$
$$
5\cos^{4}B+2\sqrt{5}\cos^{3}B+\cos^{2}B=(2-5\cos^{2}B)(1-\cos^{2}B).
$$
$$
\sqrt{5}\cos^{3}B+4\cos^{2}B-1=0.
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\cos B &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\cos A &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}
$$

Conclusion: $\tan A = 1$ and $\tan B = 2$ and $\tan C = -\tan(A+B)=3$.

There is another way to solve without calculation?

Comment: Do you mean a different method, with less calcs? maybe.  I dk

Comment: Yes. I use partial derivatives.Do you can resolver without partial derivatives?

Comment: I meant with less calculation,not less calculus. I dk. I like your work